# I am making a gallery like UI for my app, what permissions do i need to ask for if I am targetting Android 11?

Tags: android, mediastore, scoped-storage

I am using `MediaStore` to recieve the `id`s of all the images stored on the device using

```
private fun getImageUris(): List<Uri> {
        val uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        val mCursor = requireActivity().contentResolver.query(
            uri,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null
        )
        val imageUris = mutableListOf<Uri>()
        while (mCursor?.moveToNext() == true) {
            val columnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
            val imageId = mCursor.getInt(columnIndex)
            val currentImageUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, imageId.toString())
            imageUris.add(currentImageUri)
        }
        mCursor?.close()
        return imageUris
    }
```

and then i ask for the permission in `onViewCreated()` of my fragment like this:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.bind(view)

        when {
            isStoragePermissionGranted -> {
                binding.recyclerView.adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(getImageUris())
            }
            shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale -> {
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Please grant storage permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            }
            else -> {
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Permission not granted. Images cannot be shown.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect this to ask for the storage permission as soon as the app is opened (and my fragment is created) and then it should load all the images on the phone in my recycler view (I am using glide). But it doesn't work the way its expected to, instead the
`"Permission not granted. Images cannot be shown."`
toast message is shown

Comment: Well does there not open a dialog wher the user is asked to allow the read/write permission?

Comment: II think requestPermissions() is never called as it is on the wrong place in your code. Do you see that Toast()_ before it?

Comment: i never see that toast, why is that? i am confused.

Comment: I already told you why.

Comment: no i mean when ```context.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()``` is true, it should show me that toast right? an according to https://youtu.be/C8lUdPVSzDk?list=WL that constant returns true if the user hasn't denied the permission earlier. So it should show the thing for the first time right?

Comment: Well does it? You can answer that question yourself. Better: just call  requestPermissions() at a different place. Just try. Try. Try!

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time. That's what i will be doing that girl lied to me :/ i logged the constant and its always false for some reason.

Comment: You might want to consider editing your title and some of your question to exclude anything not relevant to the issue, like the type of app you might be developing etc. and it seems like the actual question is just in the second half?

Comment: > like the type of app you might be developing
How is that irrelevant to the question, I don't understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here as noted by @blackapps

```
shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale -> {
                Toast.makeText(mainActivity, "Please grant storage permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
```

because `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` is only true when the "deny and don't ask again" option is showing with the permission pop up and that option only appears after the first time the permission has been asked for (which never happens since in order for that to happen, `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` needs to be true).

Answer (score 0):

For a quick workaround, you can add this in the manifest file under `<application>`

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Read about the storage update for Android 11 [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

Comment: That helps only for a device running Android Q/10.

Comment: You have to ask read external storage permission for version below that

Comment: If you wanna list files you need a read permission on all Android versions. And how do you ask? Unclear.

Comment: deoesn't answer my question

Answer (score 0):

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

use above permission and in application write below code:

 <application
    
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"/
```